# Special use case for deprecated tabs in Android

Tags: android, tabs, deprecated

I'm working on an Android application and I want to have tabs like the old YouTube app. The concept for the layout of the app is something like this:

[image]

The idea here is that you can quickly switch between different types of input panes with the tab and that the input preview is above them. Now, I just found out that the introduction of tabs in the action bar has deprecated these types of tabs at the same time.

This is understandable, but I think changing this part of the layout will greatly affect the functionality of my app, because there's not really an alternative.

Would it be okay in this case to use the deprecated tab facilities anyway?

Comment: You're asking for opinion and discussion (whether or not it's OK is a matter of opinion), which is not appropriate for StackOverflow. But "deprecated" often indicates "may not be supported in a future version", which usually means you should replace it.

Comment: I'm not asking for an opinion whether it's okay, I'm asking if there are any other ways to go about handling this case, i.e. other kinds of UI mechanics.

Comment: I'll quote your own question: "Would it be okay...?". If that's not what you're asking, please edit your question and change it so that's not what you're asking. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tab-related features may be deprecated (and that functionality might someday stop working) but that does not stop you from implementing tabs by hand in a way that will keep working as long as the functionality you build them on continues to do approximately the same thing.

Perhaps of more concern would be the push away from that style of interface - but then it's a push, not a mandate.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are **deprecated** which you should read *"old code will yet work, but for new code, do **NOT** touch it"*. Use fragments to mimic tab functionality.

Comment: This is not an option, because in my application only part of the screen changes when switching tabs.

Comment: By saying *"only part of the screen changes when switching tabs"* you tell do not understand what fragment is ;)

Comment: @Overv: Using fragments most certainly is an option. Whether your tabs  for manipulating those fragments are in the action bar, or are added via a `PagerTabStrip`, or via a `FragmentTabHost`, is up to you.

Comment: The name **fragment** is not randomly chosen. It clearly describes the purpose of this feature. You can perfectly build your UI with as many fragments you want. Worse, you **should** do that.

Comment: @CommonsWare So wait, TabHost is deprecated, but FragmentTabHost isn't? Why is there no documentation on that? All the resources online said to use action bar tabs.

Comment: @Overv: "Why is there no documentation on that?" -- there is: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html It was released as part of the Android Support package update a week or so ago. Moreover, `TabHost` is not deprecated. `TabActivity` is.

Comment: @CommonsWare One more question, if (Fragment)TabHost is not deprecated, why is it in the support package? I thought support was only for things the new Android had and the older ones don't support.

Comment: @Overv: The Android Support package is not only for backports. If you have further concerns on this topic, please open a fresh StackOverflow question.